# Paragraphs range in collection has been altered after inserting a paragraph in officejs

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, paragraph

We are working on word add-in on word online. we have encountered an issue, where we have a list of paragraphs ranges stored in a collection and when a user inserts a new paragraph in middle, then, paragraphs ranges text which are already stored also get affected once context.sync() is executed. for example, if say, i have stored 10th paragraph in a collection, and now, user inserts a new paragraph at 10th paragraph's place. now new paragraph becomes 10th paragraph and old 10th paragraph becomes 11th paragraph which is fine. but i am not sure why the range which was stored in the collection is also reflected with new paragraph inserted.

this issue is not present in desktop vsto for word.

Thanks

M_RT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior when you are using the Office JavaScript Library. Collection objects are just proxy objects that represent the collection. Every `context.sync` refreshes the proxy object to reflect the current state of the collection in the document. Depending on your scenario, you may be able to use [TrackedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.trackedobjects?view=word-js-preview) to maintain a reference to a particular object. For more details about the use of tracked objects, see [Building Office Add-ins](http://buildingofficeaddins.com/book/).

Comment: Thanks Rick, your answer was very helpful.